# Subprogram or cursor '' reference is out of scope

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tell me how I can refer to the column when processing the current table. I need to do calculations with already calculated fields, referring to a table field through a pseudonym does not help, perhaps I am missing something else, but I will be glad if someone points out my stupidity to me. I don't see a solution in a simple place :(

*Many thanks!*

The problem lies in this place **PLS-00225: subprogram or cursor 'F' reference is out of scope:**

`then f.balance_in_rub - f.turn_cre_rub + f.turn_deb_rub`

**Body pck:**

````
create or replace package body dma.fill_f101_round_f is
  procedure Log
  ( i_message                      in varchar2
  ) 
  is
  begin
    dma.logger.writeLog('[' || c_MartName || '] ' || i_message);
  end;
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  procedure fill
  ( i_OnDate                       in date
  )
  is
  begin

    Log( '[BEGIN] fill(i_OnDate => date ''' 
         || to_char(i_OnDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd') 
         || ''');'
       );
    
    Log( 'delete on_date = ' 
         || to_char(i_OnDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
       );

    delete
      from dma.DM_F101_ROUND_F f
     where trunc(i_OnDate, 'mm')  =  from_date
       and last_day(i_OnDate)    =  to_date;
   
    Log('insert');
   
    insert 
      into dma.dm_f101_round_f f
           ( from_date         
           , to_date           
           , chapter           
           , ledger_account    
           , characteristic    
           , balance_in_rub    
           , balance_in_val    
           , balance_in_total  
           , turn_deb_rub      
           , turn_deb_val      
           , turn_deb_total    
           , turn_cre_rub      
           , turn_cre_val      
           , turn_cre_total    
           , balance_out_rub  
           , balance_out_val   
           , balance_out_total 
           )
    select trunc(i_OnDate, 'mm')                 as from_date,
           last_day(i_OnDate)                    as to_date,
           s.chapter                             as chapter,
           substr(acc_d.account_number, 1, 5)    as ledger_account,
           acc_d.char_type                       as characteristic,
           -- RUB balance
           sum( case 
                  when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
                  then b.balance_out
                  else 0
                 end
              )                                  as balance_in_rub,
          -- VAL balance converted to rub
          sum( case 
                 when cur.currency_code not in ('643', '810')
                 then b.balance_out * exch_r.reduced_cource
                 else 0
                end
             )                                   as balance_in_val,
          -- Total: RUB balance + VAL converted to rub
          sum(  case 
                 when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
                 then b.balance_out
                 else b.balance_out * exch_r.reduced_cource
               end
             )                                   as balance_in_total  ,
           -- RUB debet turnover
           sum(case 
                 when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
                 then at.debet_amount_rub
                 else 0
               end
           )                                     as turn_deb_rub,
           -- VAL debet turnover converted
           sum(case 
                 when cur.currency_code not in ('643', '810')
                 then at.debet_amount_rub
                 else 0
               end
           )                                     as turn_deb_val,
           -- SUM = RUB debet turnover + VAL debet turnover converted
           sum(at.debet_amount_rub)              as turn_deb_total,
           -- RUB credit turnover
           sum(case 
                 when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
                 then at.credit_amount_rub
                 else 0
               end
              )                                  as turn_cre_rub,
           -- VAL credit turnover converted
           sum(case 
                 when cur.currency_code not in ('643', '810')
                 then at.credit_amount_rub
                 else 0
               end
              )                                  as turn_cre_val,
           -- SUM = RUB credit turnover + VAL credit turnover converted
           sum(at.credit_amount_rub)             as turn_cre_total,
           
           sum( case 
                 when cur.currency_code     in ('643','810') and acc_d.char_type = 'A'
                 then f.balance_in_rub - f.turn_cre_rub + f.turn_deb_rub
                 
                 when cur.currency_code     in ('643','810') and acc_d.char_type = 'P'
                 then f.balance_in_rub - f.turn_cre_rub + f.turn_deb_rub
                 else 0
                end
             )                                                          as balance_out_rub,
          sum(  case 
                 when cur.currency_code not in ('643', '810') and acc_d.char_type = 'A'
                 then f.balance_in_val - f.turn_cre_val + f.turn_deb_val
                 
                 when cur.currency_code not in ('643', '810') and acc_d.char_type = 'P'
                 then f.balance_in_val + f.turn_cre_val - f.turn_deb_val
                 else 0
               end
             )                                                          as balance_out_val,
           sum (f.balance_out_val  + f.balance_out_rub)                 as balance_out_total 
      from ds.md_ledger_account_s s
      join ds.md_account_d acc_d
        on substr(acc_d.account_number, 1, 5) = s.ledger_account
      join ds.md_currency_d cur
        on cur.currency_rk = acc_d.currency_rk
      left 
      join ds.ft_balance_f b
        on b.account_rk = acc_d.account_rk
       and b.on_date  = trunc(i_OnDate, 'mm') - 1
      left 
      join ds.md_exchange_rate_d exch_r
        on exch_r.currency_rk = acc_d.currency_rk
       and i_OnDate between exch_r.data_actual_date and exch_r.data_actual_end_date
      left 
      join dma.dm_account_turnover_f at
        on at.account_rk = acc_d.account_rk
       and at.on_date between trunc(i_OnDate, 'mm') and last_day(i_Ondate)
     where i_OnDate between s.start_date and s.end_date
       and i_OnDate between acc_d.data_actual_date and acc_d.data_actual_end_date
       and i_OnDate between cur.data_actual_date and cur.data_actual_end_date
     group by s.chapter,
           substr(acc_d.account_number, 1, 5),
           acc_d.char_type;

    Log('[END] inserted ' || to_char(sql%rowcount) || ' rows.');

    commit;
    
  end;
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

end fill_f101_round_f;
/ ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **f**:

```
into dma.dm_f101_round_f f 
                         ^
                      here it is
```

**f.balance_in_rub** is this:

```
       -- RUB balance
       sum( case 
              when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
              then b.balance_out
              else 0
             end
          )                                  as balance_in_rub,
                                                --------------
                                                here it is
```

---

You can't reference a column that's being inserted simply by naming it; it is *unknown* in this context. If you want to perform some calculations, you'll have to do that with the "source" itself, i.e.

```
then f.balance_in_rub - f.turn_cre_rub + f.turn_deb_rub
```

would become

```
then
       sum(case 
              when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
              then b.balance_out
              else 0
             end
          ) -
       sum(case 
             when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
             then at.credit_amount_rub
             else 0
           end
          ) +
       sum(case 
             when cur.currency_code in ('643', '810')
             then at.debet_amount_rub
             else 0
           end
       )
```

i.e. you'd re-use all that code. Not too pretty, I'm afraid.

Another option is to do `insert` first, `update` next as you'd then just

```
update dm_f101_round_f f set
  f.balance_out_rub = f.balance_in_rub - f.turn_cre_rub + f.turn_deb_rub
where ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Then do not tell me how to do the summation operation in this context.

sum (f.balance_out_val + f.balance_out_rub) as balance_out_total

Comment: You're welcome. If you meant to say whether I *could* suggest how to compute BALANCE_OUT_TOTAL, then it would - again - be UPDATE. In there, you'd substitute e.g. BALANCE_OUT_RUB with all columns that make it: BALANCE_IN_RUB + TURN_CRE_RUB + TURN_DEB_RUB. Or do it in a 2-step UPDATE; first calculate separate columns, then calculate summaries.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Have a nice day and Happy New Year!

Comment: No problem; happy New Year!